# fall back to public repos when internal one not reachable

Tags: maven

I have an internal maven repo that I want all traffic to go through while I am on the corp network, but when I am not on the network, I would like to use public repos whenever possible.  Is there any way for me to do this in settings.xml with mirrors?  I would like to have the internal repo "mirror" external ones, but when it is not reachable to fall back to the external ones.

I would like to avoid using profiles unless they can auto-detect and fall back.  I rather not use special flags to enable/disable internal use.

Comment: What do you use as internal repo, Nexus ? Do you have control over it ?

Comment: We use artifactory as our internal repo.  I have some, but not full control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "some" control over the repo, you could configure a "repository" of your corporate repo to be a proxy of the public repos. (I use Nexus, but it dhould not be very different in artifactory).

Then you put the corporate repo and the public repos in your repository list, in the right order (corporate first, public next).

Comment: Isn't this list local?  Artifactory is acting as a proxy to public repos at the moment.  So are you saying that I should have the following?  <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://internal.repo</url>
        </repository> <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>maven-url-here</url>
        </repository>

Comment: Repos should not share the same id, but appart from that, yes, this is the idea. If you delete a dependency in your local repo (.m2 folder) you should see at the beginning of the build logs the tries maven performs. If your corporate repo is not available, you should see 2 attempts, and you should get the dependency from the maven central

Comment: So i set it up this way and deleted a internal jar.  It looks like maven is only checking maven central and not the internal repo.  The setup is <repo><id>internal-central</id>...<repo><id>central</id>... and its only checking central for the updates.

Comment: ignore the above.  I forgot to wrap the repos around a profile, so it was being ignored.